# Eigenvalues of the product of: a symmetrical Laplacian matrix; and a diagonally dominant matrix with positive diagonal terms

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, graph-laplacian

I have:

- a symmetric Laplacian matrix $L$ with the usual zero eigenvalue and all other eigenvalues have positive real parts, and:
- a strictly diagonally dominant matrix $M$ with strictly positive diagonal terms and thus with all eigenvalues having positive real parts. Note that $M$ is not diagonal - there are (small) off-diagonal terms which are not symmetric in any way.

My question is, whether I can bound the eigenvalues of $LM$ in any way? More particularly, I am interested in proving that the eigenvalues of $LM$ are have non-negative real parts.

My research so far:

1. Numerical simulations seem to indicate that this is the case, but I am ideally looking for a proof or for some theoretical condition on $M$ that guarantees that $LM$ has no negative eigenvalues for any Laplacian $L$ which has the properties above.
2. $LM$ can be interpreted as the Laplacian matrix of a directed, signed graph (i.e., with some negative edge weights). However, it is known that such graphs may have negative eigenvalues, e.g., [1].

[1] https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379517301301

Many thanks in advance for answers / guidance / helpful references.

Comment: It is notable that if $M = M^\top$, then there is a very quick proof that the eigenvalues of $LM$ are non-negative. In particular, it suffices to note that the similar matrix
$$
M^{1/2}(LM)M^{-1/2} = M^{1/2}LM^{1/2}
$$
is positive definite

Comment: You say that the eigenvalues of $M$ are "strictly positive". Typically, a "positive" number is necessarily a real number. Do you mean that $M$ necessarily has real eigenvalues, or are you saying that the eigenvalues of $M$ necessarily have *positive real part*?

Comment: Thank you very much, the eigenvalues of M necessarily have positive real parts. I have clarified this in the question. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: And yes, unfortunately M is not symmetric in any way, otherwise the proof would indeed be simple.

Comment: Here's an idea. Write $M = H + K$, where $H = (M + M^\top)/2$ symmetric and $K = (M - M^\top)/2$ skew-symmetric. We have
$$
H^{1/2}(LM)H^{-1/2} = H^{1/2}LH^{1/2} + H^{1/2}LKH^{-1/2}.
$$
It can be shown that this second term can only have imaginary eigenvalues, but I don't see how one could take advantage of that.

Comment: Are the off-diagonal entries of $M$ allowed to be negative?

Comment: echoing Ben's earlier question, this still says *'I am interested in proving that the eigenvalues of LM are non-negative.'*  what does 'non-negative' mean?  real non-negative is the standard interpretation but strictly positive has already been used in a nonstandard way so this too needs clarified

Comment: @BenGrossmann thanks, yes they can (and typically are) negative

Comment: @user8675309 thanks, I clarified this.